# How is the $ token treated when used under a label vs in a single line?

Tags: linux, x86, nasm

The NASM manual includes the following on the $ token in section 3.5:

> $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression

and earlier in section 3.1 there is a note about source lines:

> NASM uses backslash (\) as the line continuation character; if a line ends with backslash, the next line is considered to be a part of the backslash-ended line.

I have written the following assembly which allocates data as I want it to (a 20-byte array that contains a string, followed by underscores until the second-to-last index of the array, followed by a newline character):

```
section .data
  buf:                    ; define 20-byte buffer
    db 'Hello, world!'    ; declare string constant
    times 19-$+buf db '_' ; declare byte with value '_' after string and up to index 19 in buffer
    db 0xa                ; declare byte with newline character 0xa (10) at end of buffer
  len equ $-buf           ; define len to be size of buf
```

It works, but I am a little confused about why **$+buf** is used instead of **$-buf** on the fourth line. My understanding is that each line is a source line, $ refers to the beginning of the line, and buf refers to the beginning of the data labeled "buf".

If I use **$-buf** in place of **$+buf**, NASM spits out:

```
error: non-constant argument supplied to TIMES
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the fact that there's a `-` ahead of the `$` in the original.

`19-$+buf` = `buf-$ + 19`

It's still an address difference, not sum.

---

> `buf` refers to the beginning of the data labelled "buf"

Yes, but your terminology is sloppy.  `buf` is the address of the position where you put the `buf` label.  It's just a position which you can use to access bytes at known offsets from it.  There's no clear way to tell which bytes "are labelled `buf`".  In this case, probably the whole 20-byte buffer (including the newline after the line that pads with `_`) is accessed through `buf`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how to make my wording more accurate!